# How to get an image's modified date in .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net, last-modified

I am trying to get images' last modified dates for versioning at catalog page in MVC.

I've tried to use `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path)`, but it didn't work. It always returns 01/01/1601 03:00:00.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _"something like"_? What is exact value? Try to add more details to your problem, check path etc..

Comment: does this not work? File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\test.txt");

Comment: Does it return `01/01/1001` or `01.01.1601 01:00:00` ?

Comment: @Marco it returns 01/01/1601 03:00:00

Comment: And this is the reason why being exact does help us all. The documentation to `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime()` states, that this will be returned, if the file is not found.

Comment: @Marco thanks, works perfectly now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is returning the date as **'01/01/1601 03:00:00'** because your path to the file is incorrect. Below is from the Microsoft documentation

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this
>   method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

This should return the last write time, if the file actually exists (you can also add this check before reading the last write time)

```
    if (File.Exists(path)) 
    {
          Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(path));
    } 
    else
    {
          Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, problem was about files' paths. Works perfectly now!